# creating decorators. design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns

let's say two simple decorators are defined:

```
// decorated object
class Product : IComponent {
    // properties..        
    // IComponent implementation
    public Decimal GetCost() {
        return this.SelectedQuantity * this.PricePerPiece;
    }
}

// decorators
class FixedDiscountDecorator : IComponent {
    IComponent component;
    // IComponent implemantation
    public Decimal GetCost() {
        // ...
    }
    public FixedDiscountDecorator(IComponent product, Decimal discountPercentage) {
        // ...
    }
}

class BuyXGetYFreeDiscountDecorator : IComponent {
    IComponent component;
    // IComponent implemantation
    public Decimal GetCost() {
        // ...
    }
    // X - things to buy
    // Y - things you get free
    public BuyXGetYFreeDiscountDecorator(IComponent product, Int32 X, Int32 Y) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

These decorators have different constructors' signature (parameter list). I was looking for a pattern to apply to construct decorators like it could be with factory pattern. I mean I put a string and get a decorator instance.

As a result I want to simply apply a chain of decorators to a given product:

```
var product = new SimpleProduct {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    PricePerPiece = 10M,
    SelectedQuantity = 10,
    Title = "simple product"
};

var itemsToApplyTheDiscount = 5;
var itemsYouGetFree = 2;
var discountPercentage = 0.3M;

var discountA = new BuyXGetYFreeDecorator(product, itemsToApplyTheDiscount, itemsYouGetFree);
var discountB = new FixedDiscountDecorator(discountA, discountPercentage);
```

Comment: Is the data needed to construct these instances known before invoking the factory method? I.e. would you be able to call the factory method by supplying only the "previous" component instance, without any additional parameters?

Comment: I thought I could but options should be passed to the decorators to evaluate the resulting cost.

Comment: I can rely on `app.config` in those implementations without passing additional parameters. Probably it is the way.

Comment: Then it's basically dependency injection. Most DI containers provide configuration-file based instantiation (e.g. [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/XmlConfiguration.htm)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be resolved using IOC container or something similar. Some of the containers popped up in my head is `Unity`, `Windsor` and `SimpleInjector`. I will leave the IOC container to other answers since I have no experience there.

However, I really wonder why you inject a native value.

Seeing about how the class will be used, it feels weird to have an injected value like discount percentage or x buy y free item injected into the constructor.

What if the user put 10 (as percent) instead of 0.1 (as decimal) as the discount parameter? It makes ambiguity. Additionaly, if you add checks at the constructor, you give another responsibility to the class, violating SRP.

I suggest to add a DTO such as `DiscountPercentValue` or `BuyXGetYFreeValue`. Moreover, I prefer the value of discount is being set as a context or there is a repository to be injected for it. Otherwise, someday you will need `factories` to handle if-else business rules related to discounts.

EDIT1:

Usually I keep the constructor validation as `null` checks only. Other validation than that `can be` considered violation.

As for the repository things, I imagine some interfaces like these:

```
public interface IDiscountPercentageProvider{
    DiscountValue Get();
}

public interface IBuyXGetYFreeValueProvider{
    BuyXGetYFreeValue Get();
}
```

Then in your service class, you can use something like this:

```
class FixedDiscountDecorator : IComponent {
    IComponent component;
    // IComponent implemantation
    IDiscountPercentageProvider discountPercentageProvider;
    public Decimal GetCost() {
        DiscountValue discount = discountPercentageProvider.Get();
        // ...
    }
    public FixedDiscountDecorator(IComponent product
        , IDiscountPercentageProvider discountPercentageProvider) {
        // ... just null checks here
    }
}
```

This may be complicated at first. However, it provides better API design (no ambiguity now when using decorator). Using this, you can create a `DiscountValue` as a class that [protects its invariants](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/07/08/defensive-coding/), making it safer to be used in other classes.

Comment: I don't think that validating ctor input is (severe) SRP violation. Maybe I'm wrong at that. Well as for injecting (native) values it is the major problem. I want to build the ui so that user could apply one/both algorithms. I thought I could store algoithms names at the **db** and then simply use something similiar to factory, but options must be set up by user. Do you have any idea how do I resolve this. Aside. Not quite sure what do you meant about DI. Please explain.

Comment: Okay I get it about DTO/Repository.

Comment: Something like that right? so factory would rely on `repository` of parameters like `FixedDiscountValue` (`getFixedDsicountVlaue() method`), `BuyXGetFreeYValues`. Then you pass the repository as an interface to the factory and register things with DI container.

Comment: Correct, I have already updated the answer to give the abstraction. Regarding the implementation, it can be vary as how you define it.

Comment: Well dependency injection here doesn't break decorators logic as long as their creation while looking a bit dirty this is a way to go. I'll accept you answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you do show a chain of decorators applied to a given product, namely:

```
var discountA = new BuyXGetYFreeDecorator(product, itemsToApplyTheDiscount, itemsYouGetFree);
var discountB = new FixedDiscountDecorator(discountA, discountPercentage);
```

Is the question, then, what are some patterns that could be used to change the state of `product` governed by a specified property, building from your code above?  Using your example you have and limiting my scope to determining the `product` Cost:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    decimal GetCost { get; set; }
}
```

I would create a product class representing IComponent

```
public class Product
{
    public IComponent Price { get; set; }
}
```

You may have a "default" implementation in addition to the decorator classes

```
public class BasePrice : IComponent
{
    private Decimal _cost;

    public decimal GetCost //as a property maybe use Cost with get; set; in IComponent
    {
        get { return _cost; }
        set { _cost = value; }
    }
}
```

I like your two decorator classes which use IoC and implement variations of cost (GetCost()) from IComponent.

To this point I have not really added anything, only a base price class.  What I might do next is use an abstract class and defer specific operations to subclasses, as represented in the Template Method pattern.  My concrete classes would inherit from this base class.  The concrete class created will depend upon the action type passed into Factory method pattern, the class referred to below as WarrantyProcessFactory.

You mentioned using app.config ... I like enums which I would use to specify the action types to be applied to `product`.  So let's say I want to have actions tied to the product's warranty so I can process products based on this.

```
public enum WarrantyAction
{
    RefundProduct = 0,
    ReplaceProduct = 1
}
```

I will use a warranty request class to represent compensation requests by customers for defective products

```
public class WarrantyRequest
{
    public WarrantyAction Action { get; set; }
    public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePaid { get; set; }
    public decimal PostageCost { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountToRefund { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I could implement the abstract template method that will be overridden by concrete classes representative of the warranty action enums

```
public abstract class WarrantyProcessTemplate
{
    protected abstract void GenerateWarrantyTransactionFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest);
    protected abstract void CalculateRefundFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest);

    public void Process(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest)
    {
        GenerateWarrantyTransactionFor(warrantyRequest);
        CalculateRefundFor(warrantyRequest);
    }
}
```

The class and the first two methods are abstract and are required to be implemented by a subclass. The third method simply calls in the two abstract methods and passes a WarrantyRequest entity as an argument.

**Cases in which the client wants a refund**

```
public class RefundWarrantyProcess : WarrantyProcessTemplate
{
    protected override void GenerateWarrantyTransactionFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest)
    {
        // Code to determine terms of the warranty and devalutionAmt...
    }

    protected override void CalculateRefundFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest)
    {
        WarrantyRequest.AmountToRefund = warrantyRequest.PricePaid * devalutionAmt;
    }
}
```

**Cases in which the client wants a replacement product**

```
public class ReplaceWarrantyProcess : WarrantyProcessTemplate
{
    protected override void GenerateWarrantyTransactionFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest)
    {
        // Code to generate replacement order
    }

    protected override void CalculateRefundFor(WarrantyRequest warrantyRequest)
    {
        WarrantyRequest.AmountToRefund = warrantyRequest.PostageCost;
    }
}

public static class WarrantyProcessFactory
{
    public static WarrantyProcessTemplate CreateFrom(WarrantyAction warrantyAction)
    {
        switch (warrantyAction)
        {
            case (WarrantyAction.RefundProduct):
                return new RefundWarrantyProcess();
            case (WarrantyAction.ReplaceProduct):
                return new ReplaceWarrantyProcess();
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException(
                     "No Process Template defined for Warranty Action of " +
                                               warrantyAction.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Another pattern I would consider is the Strategy Method pattern.  In this case a Context class defers all calculations to a "ConcreteStrategy" referenced by its abstract class or interface.  I found Scott Millet's book "Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns" as a useful resource and often return to it.

I am open to comments and criticism.